# Create a bridge between Qemu NIC and my PCs NIC

Tags: network-adapter, bridge, qemu

I want to create a nic bridge between my qemu-Ubuntu-VM and my Windows10-Host. In VirtualBox, it's easy peasy:
[image]

I can get the Qemu-Ubuntu-VM running just fine with
`qemu-system-x86_64w -accel whpx -hda .\UbuntuServer.qcow2 -boot strict=on -machine q35 -device intel-iommu -smp 6,sockets=1,cores=6,threads=1 -m 8G -nic user -vga virtio -display gtk,show-cursor=on` but it doesn't create a bridge and Qemu has got gazillions of options, and I'm really not getting it. https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking doesn't help me at all.

**To clarify again: I have a Windows-10-HOST where I start Qemu and with Qemu I run a Linux-Guest(Ubuntu Server).**

Comment: qemu does not create a bridge for you. create one yourself with `ip link` (for transient usage) or whatever you use to persistently manage your network interfaces. It can create and enslave tap on-demand though (with e.g. `-nic bridge,br=$bridge_name`).

Comment: That doesn't help me. How am I supposed to create a bridge at startup with these commands?

Comment: `whatever you use to persistently manage your network interfaces`

Comment: That's my problem, I have a WIndows 10 machine, where I start Qemu and start a LinuxVM. Soo...how do I bridge my Windows NIC to the Qemu Linux VM Nic?

Which is why VirtualBox is so easy as shown in picture.

Comment: Oh, not Linux host / KVM? I have no idea then. (Not sure if using qemu on Windows is even a good idea. Does it even support virtualization there?)